# Building diagram in Microsoft Office Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, diagrams

Could somebody help me to build this one?

[Here's image.](http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/197065_213946071955655_100000207922679_966640_1903287_n.jpg)

This diagram tells about number of CPU cores during each year (X-axis) in TOP-500 comuters (Y-axis), digits right are number of cores. It seems to me that it would be an AREA CHART. But something wrong happens when I change Y-axis range from default to 0-500. Need your help so much. Thanx.

Comment: You're trying to do this in word?!  Surely Excel would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanx, of course. When I start to build it in Word, new Excel window opens immediatly, and there I change datas. So I have my problem in changing datas in Excel.

Comment: So tell us - what is this "wrong thing" that happens?  Can you show us what happens?

Comment: Thanx, of course: [link](http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/207525_213951505288445_100000207922679_966670_2719535_n.jpg) - if I don't change Y-axis, but it isn't what I need. [link](http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/207649_213951451955117_100000207922679_966668_6706492_n.jpg) - if I change Y-axis to what I need. Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experiments what you want is a *stacked* area graph.  You also need each column to contain the value for just that one count or processor cores:

[image]

Column F contains *=sum(B2:E2)* for each row (B3:E3 etc) to make sure that each row adds up to 500.  This is just for reference, and I'm not sure if the data is exactly what you have (I guessed at some numbers) but with each row totaling 500 the total height of each maximum point in the graph should be 500.  It auto-sizes to 600 on mine, so I have to manually tweak it to 500 to get rid of the unsightly gap at the top, but it works nonetheless.

Comment: I just cannot change Y-axis - it's always 0-1! If I change it manually  on Axis format to 0-500 I have the [this](http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/207649_213951451955117_100000207922679_966668_6706492_n.jpg) result, and nothing draws. Can you advise me what to do? Thanx.